# Spring Data ElasticSearch: Save document where some fields are dynamic

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a document I need to save in elastic search where some fields are dynamic, in a HashMap, and some fields I know in advance and can annotate with @Field and so on.

So something like this:

```
public MyClass {
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    private Map<String, Object> dynamicFields;

}
```

How would I do this? I don't know in advance, which keys will be contained in `dynamicFields`.

I would also like to define the mapping for the values in `dynamicFields`, so for instance save dates as dates and not as timestamps.

Is dynamic field mapping the way to go? If so, where can I find examples for that?